# Why is Google asking for offline access even when I have set Accesstype to online?

Tags: php, google-signin

I have this Google login code. I am trying to run it on a live server of mine. However, Google login asks the user for Offline access everytime and not for the online access and it also doesn't take the scopes. Here is what I have done:

```
$gClient = new Google_Client();
$gClient->setApplicationName('App name');
$gClient->setClientId($google_client_id);
$gClient->setClientSecret($google_client_secret);
$gClient->setRedirectUri($google_redirect_url);
$gClient->setDeveloperKey($google_developer_key);
$gClient->setAccessType('online');
$gClient->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'));
```

It still asks for offline access. I can see the access_type=online in the authentication url. But in the screen; it asks the user for offline access. Any guesses why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in this hierarchy :-

```
$gClient = new Google_Client();
$gClient->setAccessType('online');
$gClient->setApplicationName('App name');
$gClient->setClientId($google_client_id);
$gClient->setClientSecret($google_client_secret);
$gClient->setRedirectUri($google_redirect_url);
$gClient->setDeveloperKey($google_developer_key);
$gClient->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'));
```